# Does Sitecore support xamarin mobile app development

Tags: xamarin

Does sitecore has mobile api for Xamarin forms mobile app development ?

If yes, please provide links to the resources.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add that **Mobile SDK for Xamarin** with Sitecore Services Client support have been released.

Available as usual on [dev.sitecore.net](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Mobile_SDK_SSC__for_Xamarin/10/Sitecore_Mobile_SDK_SSC_10_for_Xamarin.aspx), [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sitecore.MobileSDK.SSC), [Xamarin Store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sitecore.mobilesdk.ssc), [Github](https://github.com/Sitecore/sitecore-mobile-pcl-sdk).

Answer (score 2):

Other than the above mention official resources, Sitecore MVP Goran has done lot of advance stuff where anyone will find useful

https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2016/04/13/build-an-app-with-xamarin-forms-using-sitecore-mobile-sdk-for-xamarin-getting-started/ https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2016/05/07/build-an-app-with-xamarin-forms-using-sitecore-mobile-sdk-for-xamarin-website-and-navigation-part-2/ https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2016/06/22/build-an-app-with-xamarin-forms-using-sitecore-mobile-sdk-for-xamarin-putting-it-all-together/

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore has a mobile SDK for Xamarin. Following resource might be useful

Sitecore Mobile SDK for Xamarin - Xamarin Website https://components.xamarin.com/view/Sitecore.Mobile.SDK

Xamarin Website https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sitecore.mobile.sdk

Sitecore https://github.com/Sitecore/sitecore-xamarin-pcl-sdk